# All GraphQL Scalars coming up as String (Apollo)

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo client for GraphQL client integrations. I have added the following run script, which is suggested in the official documentation.

```
cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/GraphQL/Open"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate $(find 
. -name '*.graphql') --schema schema.json 
 --output APIClient.swift
```

But the problem that is coming up is all the scalar are right now coming up as String.

For Example:-  while logging in if I create a mutation of email and password, my schema returns response as JSON while APIClient created shows response as String(instead of JSON).

Due to this there is an error received which says

```
Apollo.GraphQLResultError(path: ["login", "response"], underlying: Apollo.JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert
```

this is because String is received instead of JSON and string can not be converted into required JSON.

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I had figured it out. The solution is to add

```
--passthrough-custom-scalars
```

in the run script. This will pass custom scalars like JSON. So the complete runscript becomes

```
cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/GraphQL/Open"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate $(find 
. -name '*.graphql') --schema schema.json --passthrough-custom-scalars 
--output APIOpen.swift
```

Now when the code is recomplied along with this run script the JSON scalar becomes valid.

This took me a lot of time to figure out. Hope it helps someone and save their time. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, on more recent releases of the Apollo SDK for iOS, this flag is actually --passthroughCustomScalars. So your build script will look something like this:

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql')" --passthroughCustomScalars --schema=schema.json API.swift